# What's wrong with this IF...AND statement?

Tags: android, if-statement

I have the code below in an Android method. When I debug the code the value of callType is "upload_latest" and the value of uploaded_date (defined as long) is 1424286105554, but code execution bypasses the "return false" statement and goes straight to the string declaration below it. I know I've missed something obvious but can't work out what it is - can anyone help?

```
if (callType == "upload_latest" && uploaded_date > 0) {
    return false;
}
String extension = "";
```

Comment: if `callType` is a `String` try `callType.equals("upload_latest")`

Answer (score 1):

If `callType` is of type `String` (or any other non-primitive type), you need to use the `.equals()` method rather than the `==` operator. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To compare `String` values use `.equals`, `==` tests for reference equality.

`callType.equals("upload_latest")`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if ((callType.equals("upload_latest"))&& (uploaded_date > 0))) {
    return false;
}
String extension = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `callType.equals("upload_latest")` instead of `callType == "upload_latest"`

The == operator checks to see of the strings are the same instance where .equals() checks to see if they represent the same character sequence.